# Variable coefficient difference equation I

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, gamma-function

Consider the difference equation
\begin{align}
n \, \phi_{n+1} &= (2 \, n^{2} + 2 \, n -1) \, \phi_{n} + (n+1) \, \phi_{n-1}. 
\end{align}
It is seen that if $\phi_{n} = \Gamma(n+2) \, \theta_{n}$ then the difference equation becomes
\begin{align}
(n+1)(n+3) \, \theta_{n+2} = [2(n+1)(n+2) -1] \, \theta_{n+1} + \theta_{n}.  
\end{align}
Are there further reductions or shifts that can be made to reduce this equation further?

Answer (score 0):

If we set:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\phi_n}{n!}x^n $$
we have:
$$ F(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\phi_{n-1}}{n!}x^n,\qquad f'(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\phi_{n+1}}{n!}x^{n},\qquad f''(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\phi_{n+2}}{n!}x^{n} $$
$$ x\, f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{n \phi_{n-1}}{n!}x^n,\qquad x\,f'(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n\phi_n}{n!}x^n,\qquad x\,f''(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n\phi_{n+1}}{n!}x^n $$
and:
$$ x^2\,f''(x) = \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(n^2-n)\phi_n}{n!}x^n $$
hence our recurrence translates into:
$$ x\, f'' = 2x^2\,f''+4x\,f'+f+xf+F $$
and we may recover $\phi_n$ by solving the differential equation:

> $$ g+(x+1)g'+4x\,g''+(2x^2-x)g''' = 0.$$

Comment: Generating functions are nice, and in the case of this difference equation the linear and exponential generating functions lead to Heun differential equations. What I am interested in seeking is another transformation, say $\theta_{n} = y_{n} + f(n)$ that transforms the second equation. Another interest is the possible use of variation of parameters, if it can be done.